# The main issue is that EXISTING users cannot stay logged in

Tags: firebase, authentication, swiftui

The issue is that when an EXISTING user, meaning an already signed-up user, logs in, the app checks for an existing user and logs in, showing the TabBarView. However, when a user force closes the app and then opens it again, it displays the login view instead. Additionally, if a user is new and the signUpView sheet is shown, and the user registers and logs in, it works well. When the app is force closed and reopened, it correctly shows the TabBarView. The main issue is that EXISTING users cannot stay logged in, and there might be an issue with how the app is rendering.

This is my Login view. User signs in/up with phone number.

```
func verifyCode() {
        self.isVerifying = true
        guard let verificationID = self.verificationID else {
            print("Debug: verificationID is nil")
            return
        }
        
        // Store these for potential later use in SignUpView
        viewModel.verificationID = verificationID
        viewModel.verificationCode = verificationCode
        viewModel.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber
        
        // Check if a user with this phoneNumber already exists in Realtime Database
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
        let query = userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: self.phoneNumber)
        
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            self.isVerifying = false
            if snapshot.exists() {
                // Phone number exists, navigate to TabBarView
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)

                viewModel.isUserAuthenticated = true
            } else {
                // Phone number doesn't exist, show SignUpView
                self.showSignUpView = true
            }
        })
    }

//This is my Firebase AuthViewModel

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userIsLoggedIn = false
    @Published var agreedToTerms = false
    @Published var isUserAuthenticated: Bool = false
    @Published var verificationID: String?
    @Published var verificationCode: String?
    
    init() {
        // Attach a listener to the Auth object
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print("Debug: User is signed in, UID: \(user.uid)")
                self.isUserAuthenticated = true
            } else {
                print("Debug: User is signed out.")
                self.isUserAuthenticated = false
            }
        }
    }
       
    

    // SignUp properties
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var lastName = ""
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
    var userId: String = ""
    // Error messages for SignUp
    @Published var nameError = ""
    @Published var lastNameError = ""
    @Published var emailError = ""
    
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
    }
    
    func saveUserDataToFirebase() {
        guard isValidEmail(),
              !name.isEmpty,
              !lastName.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            let userRef = ref.child("Users").child(userId)
            
            let userData: [String: Any] = [
                "email": self.email,
                "name": self.name,
                "lastName": self.lastName,
                "phoneNumber": self.phoneNumber
            ]
            
            userRef.setValue(userData) { (error, _) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to save user info to database:", error)
                    return
                }
                print("Successfully saved user info to database.")
                self.isUserAuthenticated = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signUp() {
        // Clear errors
        emailError = ""
        nameError = ""
        lastNameError = ""
        
        if email.isEmpty || !isValidEmail() {
            emailError = "Invalid email"
        }
        
        if name.isEmpty {
            nameError = "Name is required"
        }
        
        if lastName.isEmpty {
            lastNameError = "Last name is required"
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            self.isUserAuthenticated = false
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
}

//This is my @main

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Initialize Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Register for user notifications
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            // Handle permission granted or error
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Your existing code
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // Your existing code
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            return
        }
        // Your existing remote notification handling code
    }
}

@main
struct MiaApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if viewModel.isUserAuthenticated {
                TabBarView()
                    .environmentObject(viewModel)
            } else {
                LoginView()
                    .environmentObject(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main logic should be, User should stay logged in

Comment: Try holding on to the auth listener like the “getting started” section of firebase authorization suggests